# Alternative for ConnectivityManager - NetworkInfo - getExtraInfo() as its null in Android P

Tags: android

This method started returning null in Android P (API 28)

```
private String getSSID() {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getExtraInfo() != null) {
        return StringUtils.removeQuotes(networkInfo.getExtraInfo());
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be updated to...

```
private String getSSID() {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    fina WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.getSSID() != null) {
        return StringUtils.removeQuotes(wifiInfo.getSSID());
    }

    return null;
}
```

[NetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo)

> getExtraInfo()

Returns null when not available.

Based on my testing with Android P - it seems to always be null

Comment: how about 3G, 4G, 5G?